# $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove the continuity of $f \colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x+1}.$$

I tried to use $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ So:

$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{x_0^2}{x_0+1}\right|$$

How to get to $|x - x_0|$ so that I can use $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \delta$?

Comment: Get a common denominator, then it comes down to controlling $|x^2-x_0^2|$ and $|x^2x_0-x_0^2x|$, along with ensuring the denominator doesn't get too small. Both of those two have a factor of $|x-x_0|$.

Comment: I got this numerator: x²x0 + x² - x0²x - x0² 
How can I split this numerator so that I can have |x-x0| as factor?

Comment: Group the "cubic" terms and the "quadratic" terms, as I did. Then just look at it to see what factors out.

Comment: Its a ratio of two continuous functions.

Comment: If $0<x<x_0+1$, $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=\frac{(xx_0+x+x_0)\cdot|x-x_0|}{(1+x)\cdot(1+x_0)}\leqslant(xx_0+x+x_0)\cdot|x-x_0|$$ hence $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant c(x_0)\cdot|x-x_0|,\qquad c(x_0)=(x_0+1)x_0+(x_0+1)+x_0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hope this might help you much clearly.

Comment: Wow, even better, thank you very much mate.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$
\frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{x_0^2}{x_0+1}=
\frac{x^2x_0+x^2-xx_0^2-x_0^2}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}=
\frac{xx_0+x+x_0}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}(x-x_0)
$$
Thus, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, you have
$$
\left|\frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{x_0^2}{x_0+1}\right|<
\frac{xx_0+x+x_0}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}\delta
$$
If you can find an upper bound for the factor to $\delta$, say
$$
\frac{xx_0+x+x_0}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}<M
$$
you can take $\delta=\varepsilon/M$ and then
$$
\left|\frac{x^2}{x+1} - \frac{x_0^2}{x_0+1}\right|<
\frac{xx_0+x+x_0}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}\delta<M\frac{\varepsilon}{M}=\varepsilon
$$
whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Now
$$
\frac{xx_0+x+x_0}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}=
\frac{xx_0+x+x_0+1-1}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}=
1-\frac{1}{(x+1)(x_0+1)}<1
$$
so you can use $M=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate this.